# How to get several sections of a string with a single regex using C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have seen how to do this in java but have had no success either getting the result or finding the answer on SO of how to do this with C#, so here it goes.

I have a string with a regular ping result:

```
var result = "PING skye.net (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx): 200 data bytes" +
   "208 bytes from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: icmp_seq=0 ttl=253 time=1.759 ms" +
   "208 bytes from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: icmp_seq=1 ttl=253 time=2.075 ms" +
   "208 bytes from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: icmp_seq=2 ttl=253 time=1.843 ms" +
   "208 bytes from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: icmp_seq=3 ttl=253 time=1.803 ms" +
   "208 bytes from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: icmp_seq=4 ttl=253 time=17.898 ms" +
   "--- skye.net ping statistics ---" +
   "5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0% packet loss" +
   "round-trip min/avg/max = 1.759/5.075/17.898 ms";
```

I would like to get the transmitted, received and loss results with a single Regex.Match or Regex.Matches call.

For each section I do have the individual regex patterns:
- (\d+)\spackets\stransmitted
- (\d+)\spackets\sreceived
- (\d+%)\spacket\sloss

And they work fine individually with Regex.Match.

So instead of doing this:

```
var result = "PING skye.net (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx): 200 data bytes" +
    "208 bytes from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: icmp_seq=0 ttl=253 time=1.759 ms" +
   "208 bytes from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: icmp_seq=1 ttl=253 time=2.075 ms" +
   "208 bytes from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: icmp_seq=2 ttl=253 time=1.843 ms" +
   "208 bytes from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: icmp_seq=3 ttl=253 time=1.803 ms" +
   "208 bytes from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: icmp_seq=4 ttl=253 time=17.898 ms" +
   "--- skye.net ping statistics ---" +
   "5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0% packet loss" +
   "round-trip min/avg/max = 1.759/5.075/17.898 ms";

const string patternForTransmitted = @"(\d+)\spackets\stransmitted";
const string patternForReceived = @"(\d+)\spackets\sreceived";
const string patternForLoss = @"(\d+%)\spacket\sloss";

var transmitted = Match(patternForTransmitted, result);
var received = Match(patternForReceived, result);
var loss = Match(patternForLoss, result);
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
    var result = "PING skye.net (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx): 200 data bytes" +
        "208 bytes from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: icmp_seq=0 ttl=253 time=1.759 ms" +
       "208 bytes from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: icmp_seq=1 ttl=253 time=2.075 ms" +
       "208 bytes from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: icmp_seq=2 ttl=253 time=1.843 ms" +
       "208 bytes from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: icmp_seq=3 ttl=253 time=1.803 ms" +
       "208 bytes from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: icmp_seq=4 ttl=253 time=17.898 ms" +
       "--- skye.net ping statistics ---" +
       "5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0% packet loss" +
       "round-trip min/avg/max = 1.759/5.075/17.898 ms";

var pattern = @"((\d+)\spackets\stransmitted)((\d+)\spackets\sreceived)((\d+%)\spacket\sloss)";

var matches = Regex.Matches(pattern, result);
```

Is it doable?

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you use the [Ping class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) instead of running an external process and then parsing the result of it.

Comment: @Eser - That is an excellent questions :) The reason is that the project we are working on has a complex set of requirements, infrastructure and other things that are specific to our customer (do not have the liberty to discuss details or customer name) for which the use of the ping class is not feasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct regex is:

```
@"(\d+)\spackets\stransmitted.*(\d+)\spackets\sreceived.*(\d+%)\spacket\sloss"
```

Test [here](https://regex101.com/r/eO2rH2/1)

Answer (score 0):

The regex would be like this:

```
var pattern =@"((\d+)\spackets\stransmitted)|((\d+)\spackets\sreceived)|((\d+%)\spacket\sloss)";
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mF3pY3/1)

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Oleh is correct, but in case you only need the numeric values then try this:

```
var pattern = @"(\d+)\spackets\stransmitted|(\d+)\spackets\sreceived|(\d+%)\spacket\sloss"
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/mF3pY3/2

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
    var result = "PING skye.net (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx): 200 data bytes " +
        "208 bytes from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: icmp_seq=0 ttl=253 time=1.759 ms " +
       "208 bytes from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: icmp_seq=1 ttl=253 time=2.075 ms " +
       "208 bytes from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: icmp_seq=2 ttl=253 time=1.843 ms " +
       "208 bytes from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: icmp_seq=3 ttl=253 time=1.803 ms " +
       "208 bytes from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: icmp_seq=4 ttl=253 time=17.898 ms " +
       "--- skye.net ping statistics --- " +
       "5 packets transmitted, 6 packets received, 7% packet loss " +
       "round-trip min/avg/max = 1.759/5.075/17.898 ms ";

var pattern = @"(\d+)\spackets\stransmitted, (\d+)\spackets\sreceived, (\d+%)\spacket\sloss";

var matches = Regex.Match(result, pattern);

Console.WriteLine(matches.Groups[1].Captures[0].Value);
Console.WriteLine(matches.Groups[2].Captures[0].Value);
Console.WriteLine(matches.Groups[3].Captures[0].Value);
```

You can adjust the whitespace and such but I think the key here is now to access the groups in the returned result.  Also you had result and pattern reversed in your call.

I'd also take the `%` out of the capture, but that is me.